# Staying at Ace vs staying at the Ace; Ace Hotel

Tags: articles

Name of hotel is "Ace Hotel". Which is correct: "I am staying at Ace", "I am staying at the Ace" or neither?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever a hotel calls itself, we always seem to use "the" when naming them.

<s>"I'm staying at Hilton"</s> => "I'm staying at the Hilton"
 
<s>"I'm staying at Holiday Inn"</s> => "I'm staying at the Holiday Inn"

Here's an ngram: ["staying at Hilton,staying at the Hilton,staying at Holiday Inn,staying at the Holiday Inn"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=staying%20at%20Hilton%2Cstaying%20at%20the%20Hilton%2C%20staying%20at%20Holiday%20Inn%2C%20staying%20at%20the%20Holiday%20Inn&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstaying%20at%20Hilton%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstaying%20at%20the%20Hilton%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstaying%20at%20the%20Holiday%20Inn%3B%2Cc0)

So it will not be "I'm staying at Ace." But can we say "I'm staying at the Ace?"

It certainly fits the pattern, it's just a question of whether your listener would know that you meant *the Ace Hotel* when you say "the Ace." In a context where it's clear you're talking about a hotel, you can omit "hotel", for example, "I'm staying at the Embassy Suites. Where are you staying?" "The Ace."With large, very well-established hotel chains (Hilton, Sheraton, Best Western, etc.), their names are so well known, you don't need to include "hotel" even in an ambiguous context, for example: "I just came from the Hilton."

So is the Ace Hotel known well enough to omit "hotel?" I would guess that it's not.  There's an Ace Hotel where I live, but if you told me, "I just came from the Ace" I would probably not understand that you meant the Ace Hotel.